# How to set inventory of all product fom 9999 to 1

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory

I have a client who has set the inventory of all products in 9999 pieces. Now he wants to use the warehouse management.
It should all products are reset to 1. Is it possible to automatically make?

Maybe with a SQL-Query?
Or an extension?
We use **Magento 1.9.0.1**

Thank you ever

Answer (score 6):

If you're not deep into MySQL queries or if you don't have a direct access to database, you can do the same in the Magento back-office.

Go to `Catalog -> Manage product`, in the product table header on the left click on "select all" and then in the same bar at right "updated attribute" and "submit". 
You can do that operation filtering only the product you need, by using the bar filters before clicking `"select all"`.

It will open a new cumulative form, navigate to tab `"inventory"` and modify the value.

Comment: Nice alternative for those not comfortable editing directly.

Comment: thanks a lot! I did not know that it's so easy.

Answer (score 5):

The inventory is kept in the table `cataloginventory_stock_item`. The column you are looking  for is `qty`.

Run this query:

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = 1;
```

But make sure you backup first and rebuild the indexes when you are done.